# Use multithreading or Multiprocessing to speed up my script

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, class, multiprocessing

I create a script that receive random letters as input and generate possible words, then extract readable words from comparing my list items with file containing english words.

for example when I enter as input : **eys**

this will generate a list like :

> ["esy", "eys", "sey", "sye", "yes", "yse"]

and return the correct readable word **"yes"** as a final result.

The problem is when the length of input is greater than 8 characters it takes much time and I want to use Threading or Multiprocessing to reduce the latency.

````
'''Create script that generate readable english words from given letters'''

    from math import factorial
    from itertools import permutations
    from time import time, ctime
    from threading import Thread
    import multiprocessing as mp
    
    class GetReadableWords:
    
        def __init__(self, letters):
            self.letters = letters
    
        def prob_words(self):
            
            self.comb = factorial(len(self.letters))
            print('Nomber of combinitions that we have is : ', self.comb)
    
            self.prob = [''.join(ltr) for ltr in permutations(self.letters)]
            return self.prob
    
        def chek_word(self):
    
            result = []
    
            for word in set(self.prob_words()):
    
                with open('corncob_lowercase.txt', 'r') as f:
    
                    for line in f.readlines():
                        line = line.rstrip()
    
                        if word == line:
                            result.append(word)
    
                        else:
                            continue
    
                    f.close()
    
            return result
    
        '''def run(self):
            with mp.Pool() as pool:
                pool.map(self.chek_word(), self.prob, chunksize=1)'''
    
    
    if __name__ == "__main__":
    
        user_input = input('Enter your random characters : ')
        
        sart_time = time()
        print("starting time at : ", ctime(sart_time).split(' ')[3])
    
        c = GetReadableWords(user_input)
    '''
        threads = []
        for word in c.prob_words():
            p = mp.Process(target=c.chek_word(), args=(word,))
            threads.append(p)
            p.start()
    
        for job in jobs:
            job.join()
    '''
        #print(c.run())
        print(c.chek_word())
        end_time = time()
        print("ending time at : ", ctime(end_time).split(' ')[3])
    
        elaps_t = (end_time - sart_time)
        print("time taken is : %.2f sec" % elaps_t)```
````

Comment: Apologies I don't actually know how to improve this particular script but I wanted to say you may want to try and find a more efficient way of achieving your goal since the number of iterations is `n!` so with 8 characters it's 40320 operations and going up to just 10 is over 3.6 million. Multiprocessing will only help so much with such large datasets. Also consider using a virtual machine or something similar to protect your system as I have crashed my computer many times attempting to implement multiprocessing. Sorry I couldn't be more help, best of luck!

Comment: multiprocessing or multithreading won't make things better there:there are lots of things to improve in this script before thinking about that. And even when it is fixed, it may be that parallelising this brings no further improvements.

Maybe you'd be better posting this on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ , another site on stackoverflow's network, since this requires a major rewrite, with several points where one can teach you interesting stuff.

Comment: This might help: https://medium.com/@willsentance/how-to-write-your-own-spellchecker-and-autocorrect-algorithm-in-under-80-lines-of-code-6d65d21bb7b6

Comment: [Cross-posted to Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/276610/9357). Voting to close on Stack Overflow as it does not contain the shortest relevant code.

Answer (score 0):

As has been commented I don't believe that multiprocessing can improve the performance because multiprocessing brings with it overhead you would not normally have (such as creating the processes and moving data between different address spaces) so for performance to be improved the work done by each process must be great enough so that this additional loss in performance due to multiprocessing is more than offset by the gain in performance by parallelizing the processing. In this case, I don't believe it is.

But has also been pointed out is that your current code can use a lot of improvement. For example, to check if each permuted "word" is in file of words you read in and process the file once for each word. This is incredibly wasteful. It is far better to read in the file once upfront and build a set of the words found in the file and to then check each permuted word against that set. You are also creating a list out of all the possible permutations. This list will have a length of N! where N is the number of letters input. This could take up a lot of space when N is large.

Notwithstanding what I said about multiprocessing probably not being more performant than well-coded sequential processing, I include below how I would implement the multiprocessing version (others would probably come up with different and perhaps better implementations). I have in so doing made some subtle and not so subtle changes to your original code; some of these are just cosmetic but I believe them all to be an improvement. You should therefore look at each line carefully.

But first:

**Modified Non-Multiprocessing Version**

```py
from math import factorial
from itertools import permutations
from time import time, ctime
import multiprocessing as mp

class GetReadableWords:

    def __init__(self, letters):
        self.generate_permutations_from_letters(letters)
        # Build set of all the words in the file:
        file_words = set()
        with open('corncob_lowercase.txt', 'r') as f:
            for line in f.readlines():
                file_words.add(line.rstrip().lower())
        self.file_words = file_words
        self.found_words = []

    def generate_permutations_from_letters(self, letters):
        n_permutations = factorial(len(letters))
        print('Number of permutations that we have is:', n_permutations)
        self.n_permutations = n_permutations
        self.permutations = permutations(letters)

    def check_words(self):
        for permutation in self.permutations:
            word = ''.join(permutation)
            if word in self.file_words:
                self.found_words.append(word)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    user_input = input('Enter your random characters: ').lower()

    start_time = time()
    print("Starting time at:", ctime(start_time).split(' ')[3])

    grw = GetReadableWords(user_input)
    grw.check_words()

    end_time = time()
    print("Ending time at:", ctime(end_time).split(' ')[3])
    elaps_t = (end_time - start_time)
    print("Time taken is: %.2f sec" % elaps_t)

    print("Found words:", grw.found_words)
```

Then:

**Multiprocessing Version**

```py
from math import factorial
from itertools import permutations
from time import time, ctime
import multiprocessing as mp

class GetReadableWords:

    def __init__(self, letters):
        self.generate_permutations_from_letters(letters)
        # Build set of all the words in the file:
        file_words = set()
        with open('corncob_lowercase.txt', 'r') as f:
            for line in f.readlines():
                file_words.add(line.rstrip().lower())
        self.file_words = file_words

    def generate_permutations_from_letters(self, letters):
        n_permutations = factorial(len(letters))
        print('Number of permutations that we have is:', n_permutations)
        self.n_permutations = n_permutations
        self.permutations = permutations(letters)

    def compute_chunksize(self, iterable_size, pool_size):
        chunksize, remainder = divmod(iterable_size, 4 * pool_size)
        if remainder:
            chunksize += 1
        return chunksize

    def check_words(self):
        pool_size = mp.cpu_count()
        chunksize = self.compute_chunksize(self.n_permutations, pool_size)
        pool = mp.Pool(pool_size)
        self.found_words = list(
            filter(
                lambda word: word,
                pool.imap_unordered(self.check_word, self.permutations, chunksize=chunksize)
            )
        )
        pool.close()
        pool.join()

    def check_word(self, permutation):
        word = ''.join(permutation)
        return word if word in self.file_words else None

if __name__ == "__main__":

    user_input = input('Enter your random characters: ').lower()

    start_time = time()
    print("Starting time at:", ctime(start_time).split(' ')[3])

    grw = GetReadableWords(user_input)
    grw.check_words()

    end_time = time()
    print("Ending time at:", ctime(end_time).split(' ')[3])
    elaps_t = (end_time - start_time)
    print("Time taken is: %.2f sec" % elaps_t)

    print("Found words:", grw.found_words)
```